# What is the difference between textureregion and atlasregion in LibGdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I was wondered what the difference is. And can someone also say what the diference between texture and textureatlas.

Greetz Luc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load a texture in your game by doing `Texture t = new Texture("");`, you load a texture in GPU.

TextureRegion, takes an area from the Texture according to the dimension you provide, the advantage of having it is that you don't have to load textures again and again and the bigger advantage is you don't have to load each and every texture on GPU as you can do it directly by loading one big texture and extracting sub regions(TextureRegions) from it.

Now because you want to use `TextureRegions`, it will be hard to know the dimensions of each and every sub image to load them from Texture Sheet. So what we do is we pack the Textures into a bigger Texture using TexturePacker(an application) which then creates a `.pack` file. It will pack every texture into one image AND create a .pack file. Now when you load the .pack file, it is loaded using `TextureAtlas` class
For example imagine a pokemon pack file which has all the pokemons into it.

```
 TextureAtlas  pokemonFrontAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("pokemon//pokemon.pack"));
```

Now imagine you packed 100 files using Texture Packer and you want to load a image(`Texture`) which has file name as "SomePokemon".

Now to get a particular TextureRegion from it, you do

```
pokemonFrontAtlas.findRegion("SomePokemon")
```

findRegion(String name) returns you the textureRegion from the `TextureAtlas`.

So to sum it up, the major difference is, `TextureRegion` is a Region from a Texture whereas <strike>`TextureAtlas` is a collection of `TextureRegions`.</strike>

**EDIT**

A `TextureAtlas` class contains a collection of `AtlasRegion` class which extends `TextureRegion` class.

See Javadocs for more details
[TextureAtlas](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.html)

Comment: Thanks! But is textureregion the same as atlasregion? And can you also explain the difference between .pack and .json?

Comment: See updated answer, they both are not same. TextureAtlas contains collection of AtlasRegion which extends TextureRegion class so they are not same.
Also .pack and .json are two different files, .json is used for creating skins in atlas whereas .pack files hold details of AtlasRegion. For more details I will advise you to post a new question as this is out of scope here.

Comment: Have a look at this answer too, it is much better explained.
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/66623/what-are-the-differences-betwen-texture-textureregion-textureatlas-sprite-and

Answer (score 4):

- A `Texture` is the libGDX implementation of an OpenGL 2D Texture. That is: it represents a single 2D texture in GPU memory, which can be used for rendering. You typically want to use as less textures as possible (and specifically want to avoid switching between textures). Therefor it is common to include multiple images in a single bigger `Texture`.
- A `TextureRegion` is used to define a region of a `Texture`. Practically it thus says: "on that texture at those coordinates and those dimensions this image is located".
- A `TextureAtlas` is a container for both one or more `Texture`s and the regions it contains. You typically load a `TextureAtlas` from a file which holds all information about the atlas. This file is typically created with the `TexturePacker` tool. Note that an atlas can contain multiple texture files.
- A `AtlasRegion` is an `TextureRegion` that contains additional information about the packing. E.g. when the region is rotated for optimal packing, then the `AtlasRegion` contains this information so it knows it has to undo that operation when drawing it. Likewise, if you used whitespace stripping when packing the atlas for a more tight packing, then `AtlasRegion` contains the required information to reproduce the original image.